# Request method 'POST' not supported - Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I want the passenger details to my savePassenger function using request mapping but it is showing me error.

[Controller savePass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRH0q.png)

[JPA file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyp0Y.png)

[JPA file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMbpE.png)

It is Showing this Message

[org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post code as code and not as links to images.

Comment: Your form action is of type “post”, but you only have a method of type “get” in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Controller method of savePass is get(RequestMethod.GET) but in your jpa file form action savePass method is post, they should match each other. Please edit the method of controller method to RequestMethod.POST. Please have a try.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/savePass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post code as code and not as links to images.

Answer (score 0):

Use **RequestMethod.POST**
`@RequestMapping(value = "/savePass", method = RequestMethod.POST)`
instead of

`@RequestMapping(value = "/savePass", method = RequestMethod.Get)` then you will be able to call post .